# Qt Creator stdin on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, stdin

I can not get standard input to work in Qt Creator 3.5.1 on Windows 7 64b.

I have checked "Run in Terminal" in  Project settings.

I have added `CONFIG += console` to the .pro file.

I do get a terminal window opened when running the program, but it doesn't accept any input.

What am I missing?

Code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::string str;
    while(true){
        std::cin >> str;
        std::cout << "Read " << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running the application from the command line and not through QtCreator.

Comment: Funny, after reboot it worked fine. In the meantime, I've tried it in Ubuntu and from the command line, where it worked fine, but that's not a solution to the problem I had :D I wasn't even the only one with the problem, Google says.